# Why Xen Cloud Platform XCP is not offering every feature as promised?

Tags: virtualization, xen, xenserver

I have installed XCP (Xen Cloud Platform) 1.1 on my machine and installed XEN Centre (**version 6.0**) on my windows xp

i created VM and its running just like in XEN server Free,but its not allowing to take snapshot,template etc its showing "**requires xen 5.5 or later**".

Also its not allowing to use VM Protection policies showing **requires XEN 6 or later**.

I installed XCP based on the comparison described here but i am not getting features mentioned  there..Should i use any other tool for making this thing to work..??

http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XCP/XenServer_Feature_Matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps solve the problem

http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenCenterXCP

1.enable snapshots in XenCenter

echo "5.6.100" > /etc/xensource/xapi_version_override

/etc/init.d/xapi restart

On each Linux guest with xe-guest-utilities (Xen Tools) installed:

sed -i /usr/sbin/xe-update-guest-attrs -e 's/MajorVersion" "1"/MajorVersion" "5"/'

sed -i /usr/sbin/xe-update-guest-attrs -e 's/MinorVersion" "1"/MinorVersion" "6"/'

sed -i /usr/sbin/xe-update-guest-attrs -e 's/MicroVersion" "0"/MicroVersion" "100"/'

Comment: Please can you edit including a summary, we don't just link to other site here in case the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound kind of stupid but...what version of Xen Center are you running, is it under 5.5...?

Make sure your on XenServer 6.

Comment: i am using XCP 1.1 and using xen centre 6.0.
with xen sever 6.0 i was able to take snapshot and create templates.. but with this that is also not possible.What am i missing??